# Советы по рефакторингу метода

Tags: java, android, retrofit, рефакторинг

Написал метод, который в зависимости от выбранной ссылки (youtube/vimeo/...) будет позволять нам вставлять в preview картинку из этого видео.
Но на данном этапе получилось немного громоздко, хотелось бы сократить, возможно что-то стоит вынести в особый класс, буду рад любым ремаркам. 
Код программы:

```
void getIdUrl(String url, int position) {
    String video_id = "";
    String expression = "";
    if (url != null && url.trim().length() > 0 && url.matches(".*\\byoutube\\b.*")) {
        expression = "^.*((youtu.be" + "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*"; 

        CharSequence input = url;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
            if (groupIndex1 != null && groupIndex1.length() == 11)
                video_id = groupIndex1;
        }

        controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().get(0).setLoadImage(true);
        controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().get(0).getOutputMetadata().setVideoUrl("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg");
        controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().get(0).getOutputMetadata().setFilename("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg");
        adapterForm.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else if (url.matches(".*\\bvimeo\\b.*")) {
        expression = "/vimeo.com/([^_]+)/?";
        Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
        Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group();
            String tem = match.substring(match.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            System.out.println("ID : " + match.substring(match.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            uploadVideo(position,tem);
        }

    } else if(url.matches(".*\\bplay\\b.*")) {
        expression = "/play.md/([^_]+)/?";
        Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
        Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group();
            String tem = match.substring(match.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            System.out.println("ID : " + match.substring(match.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().get(0).setLoadImage(true);
            controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().get(0).getOutputMetadata().setVideoUrl("https://play.md/"+tem+"/thumbnail");
            controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().get(0).getOutputMetadata().setFilename("https://play.md/"+tem+"/thumbnail");
            adapterForm.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Для vimeo использовал retrofit:

```
private void uploadVideo(final int pos,String idVideo) {
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("https://vimeo.com/api/v2")
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();

    API service = adapter.create(API.class);

   service.uploadVideo(idVideo, new Callback<ArrayList<VideoUpload>>() {

        @Override
        public void success(ArrayList<VideoUpload> videoUpload, Response response) {
            controlList.get(pos).getImageUploads().get(0).setLoadImage(true);
            controlList.get(pos).getImageUploads().get(0).getOutputMetadata().setVideoUrl(videoUpload.get(0).getUserPortraitHuge());
            controlList.get(pos).getImageUploads().get(0).getOutputMetadata().setFilename(videoUpload.get(0).getUserPortraitHuge());
            adapterForm.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("succes", "sisisihjdf");
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d("errlor", error.getMessage().toString());
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `url.trim().length() > 0 && url.matches(".*\\byoutube\\b.*")` левое выражение лишнее, так как если длина 0, то правое выражение не сработает.

Comment: `controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().get(0).` 6 раз вызывается, можно вызвать один раз, запомнить Объект и использовать этот объект

Comment: Можно сделать декомпозицию через [паттерн](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). В любом случае не стоит оставлять такую простыню кода.